# GET values from variables with [] in url

Tags: php, url, parameters, get, request

I have a URL like this

```
?custom[weight]=1&custom[weight2]=2
```

If i use echo `$_GET[custom[weight]]` then it doesn't work. How do i retrive this value?

Comment: You access it like `$_GET['custom']['weight']` this returns `1` 
Or `$_GET['custom']['weight2']` will return `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access it with `$_GET['custom']['weight']` and `$_GET['custom']['weight2']`

You can check it with `print_r($_GET)` and you'll get something like,

```
Array
(
    [custom] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 1
            [weight2] => 2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the provided example `$_GET` becomes multidimensional and `custom` is an index with the array so you want.

```
foreach( $_GET['custom'] as $index => $value) { 
     echo $index . ' has the value of ' .  $value . PHP_EOL; 
}
```